# VB.NET as a game development tool

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I come from a Mac background. I developed games with Xcode and Objective-C frameworks.

Recently I moved to Windows and decided to use VB.NET for a while. It is cool.

Here is my intention:
I want to develop a Windows platform game. The game is rather complex, and I will need some kind of "engine" or "editor" to be able to edit my levels and properties easily. The idea is that I can build most of the game with this editor and then the editor will compile the project files and resources into one .exe file for gaming.

Fortunately, I was able to create my editor with VB.NET. I am able to edit levels and such. However, I am not sure about the "compilation" part to create a .exe file and play the game.

Basically I am at the point of designing the "Compile" button in my editor. But I am clueless. I could not find much documentation regarding this topic.

My editor has all variables and information the game needs to run.

I assume that this .exe file is like another VB.NET project (produced by my editor) that will basically take the data it comes with and "run" the game loop alright.

Any ideas, links, etc? Thanks.

**Note: my game is a 2d game with, probably, a vast amount of sprites and such.

Comment: You can create a `.exe` with a ZIP file and a wrapper, IIRC.

Comment: From what you say, it sounds like you want your level editor's compile button to output an exe with all the required level resources and so on embedded into the game exe? You've probably already considered this, but wouldn't it be simpler to simply compress all the other game assets into a zip file (or similar) and include that with the game executable?

Comment: Why do you want to compile resources to an EXE?

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't explain properly. What I meant was for the editor to produce the "whole package needed to play a game". So I need it to create a .exe that can run the project, plus all resources required (separately).

Comment: Wait, simpler: How do I create, using VB.NET, a 2d game engine? Where you edit your project and then click "compile" and Ta-Da, you get a bundle of files and a .exe to play a game.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio is a fantastic IDE for development of Windows apps.  Compiling the project is pretty simple.  You just compile and it gives you an exe that's in the .NET Framework.  Microsoft also has [XNA Game Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb200104.aspx) to help with game design if you want to look at gaming frameworks for .NET.

Also, you can take files from your editor if they generate vb.net and use the vbc compiler command to compile them into libraries, executables, whatever you like.  The command could be something like this:

```
vbc /reference:Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll File.vb
```

Here's a link to the [.NET command line compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dehewf5.aspx) for VB.NET.

Comment: The OP wants their VB.NET program to spit out binaries without Visual Studio.

Comment: I reread and realized that.  I've updated my answer to provide a command line sample to compile a file into an executable. Thanks Blender.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean here.  Are you saying that you have an editor (something like a level or map editor?) for your game, and that you want the output of this editor to be embedded into the exe for your actual game application when it compiles?

If that's the case (or something similar to it) then you'll first want to consider how to persist your data to file.  Then you could manually add files you've created as embedded resources.  Or better yet, create a file type that holds as many 'levels' or 'maps' as you need and embed that.  This way as you create more they will just get added to that file and you won't have to keep adding more embedded resources.